Table row flickering after useReducer update
I have a table with data, that can be edited. The edition process triggers a modification in the table with useReducer.
The problem is the styling. The table rows have a hover effect but useReducer triggers the rerender of the whole table. So after the update, it's causing a flickering for a fraction of a second. It's very annoying.
This is table component:
return (
        <div id={id} style={{ animation: 'bgFadeIn 0.6s ease' }}>
            <div className="changes-filters">
                {typeContent().newButton}
                {typeContent().radioButtons}
                <div className="changes-search-box">
                    <div className="changes-search-icon">
                        <GrSearch />
                    </div>
                    <input className="changes-search" placeholder="Buscar" onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
                    <div className="changes-search-icon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {listData.filter.length ? (
                <table className={`table-${rowType}`}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {headersList.map((h) => (
                                <th key={h.key} onClick={() => headerClickHandler(h.key, h.title)}>
                                    <div className="table-header">
                                        <div className="th-title">{h.title}</div>
                                        <div
                                            type="button"
                                            className={`${h.key === 0 ? 'arrow-down  arrow-active' : 'arrow-down'}`}
                                        >
                                            <BiDownArrow style={{ color: 'white' }} size={14} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                            {(rowType === 'change' || rowType === 'user') && <th>Historial</th>}
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {listData.filter.map((item) => (
                            <Row
                                key={Math.random() * 1000}
                                type={rowType}
                                data={item}
                                modifyCallback={resultModifyRow}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            ) : (
                <div className="no-data">
                    <Title text={'No hay datos para mostrar.'} />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

The hover effect it's just this:
tbody > tr:hover {
    background-color: #b1dffa;
}
}

Here's the callback function:
const resultModifyRow = (response, remove) => {
        if (response.result) {
            dispatch({
                payload: {
                    type: 'modify',
                    data: response,
                    remove: remove,
                },
            });
            if (remove) {
                toast(resultMessage('delete'), { type: 'success' });
            } else {
                toast(resultMessage('modify', response.result.status), { type: 'success' });
            }
        }
        if (response.error) {
            toast(resultMessage(), { type: 'error' });
        }
    };

And here's the reducer:
function reducer (state, action){
        const modifyList = (response, removeItem) => {
            let newItemsList = { ...listData };
            let itemIndex = newItemsList.fetched.findIndex((i) => i._id === response.result._id);
            if (removeItem) {
                newItemsList.fetched.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            } else {
                let pId = newItemsList.fetched[itemIndex].priorityId;
                newItemsList.fetched[itemIndex] = response.result;
                newItemsList.fetched[itemIndex].priorityId = pId;
            }
            return newItemsList;
        };

    switch (action.payload.type) {
            case 'modify': {
                return modifyList(action.payload.data, action.payload.remove);
            }
}

The whole reducer function it's WAY bigger and complex. But it makes no sense to post it all, you wouldn't undertand.
The point it's the rerendering process causing a flickering on the table row. How can I fix this??
Thanks.
I tried adding the hover effect as a class:
.hover-effect {
    tbody > tr:hover {
        background-color: #b1dffa;
    }
}

And then toggle the class when an update it's in process and after the dispatch function. But it keeps flickering.
